# Focal Loss in Pytorch implementation

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, computer-vision

Where can I find a reliable Pytorch implementation of Focal Loss for a multi-class object detection problem? I have seen some implementations on GitHub, but I am looking for the official Pytorch version, similar to `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`.

My prediction has a shape of `(b, c)` and the target has a shape of `(b)`, where `b` is the batch size and c is the number of classes. If there is no official implementation from Pytorch team, does anyone know a good GitHub implementation that supports different shapes for target and prediction?